# Creating Snowflake s3 Stages Based on Select

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in Snowflake that essentially maps identifiers to the groups that they belong to. 
For each of those groups, I need to create an s3 stage / file that contains their identifiers.

Is there a way to do this with SnowSQL, or will I need to look elsewhere? Any assistance is appreciated!

```
Table Example:
+----+-------+
| id | group |
+----+-------+
|  1 | bob   |
|  2 | bob   |
|  3 | bob   |
|  4 | tim   |
|  5 | tim   |
|  6 | carl  |
+----+-------+

s3 Post-Staging:
s3://myFolder/file=BOB/bob.txt
s3://myFolder/file=TIM/tim.txt
s3://myFolder/file=CARL/carl.txt

File Contents:
bob.txt --> 1, 2, 3
tim.txt --> 4, 5
carl.txt -- > 6
```

Comment: Creating the external S3 stages is easy enough as shown here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-create-stage.html#creating-an-external-stage Then use a COPY INTO with a select to get the data from the table and write to the 3 different files in the 3 stages, one by one: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html#validating-data-to-be-unloaded-from-a-query Use the CSV file format type (it defines basic text delimited file types) with comma as the delimiter. Hope this helps.

Comment: @MikeDonovan thanks for the comment! I was more looking for a way to dynamically create those stages, which I ended up doing by using the snowflake-to-python connector and iterating through each of the names to create a separate stage.